# How to create a docker image combing two services: postgres and nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I was looking to build a docker image for [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/). It is a nodeJS frontend for the postgres database. So basically, I was looking to have a docker image with the PostgreSQL database whose ports are completely hidden, and the external world can only use the database functions via JavaScript/NodeJS.

I searched around and found mostly found links about how to do this using docker-compose, e.g. [here](https://github.com/alexeagleson/docker-node-postgres-template). *But docker-compose isn't what I am looking for*, because I might need to use this in a different environment (e.g. k8s) and because I don't need any of the original postgresql interface. For all intents and purposes, the database isn't needed outside, only the nodeJS interface is needed. It's better if nodeJS+postgres show up as one unit/service. On the docker side, the closest thing I could find so far is this [dockerhub image](https://hub.docker.com/r/spittet/node-postgresql), which is 7 years old and I couldn't find its Dockerfile.

To write the Dockerfile myself, I am not sure about a few things.

First, which base image should I use, [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) or [node](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/)?

I am familiar with Ubuntu, and can `apt install` postgresql inside a dockerfile. But the official [postgres docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) seems to have different entry points than how I would run postgresql as a background service in Ubuntu or a VM. I suppose there are similar issues with the official node image in terms of entry point.

So the question is:

Should I use the postgres image as the base and replicate the steps of the nodejs Dockerfile, or use the node image as the base and replicate the steps of the postgres Dockerfile?

It'll be great if any one with the prior experience can help explain the main steps or share any insights.

**-- Clarification --**

As pointed out in the comments, it is generally not a good idea to have multiple processes in one container. I also understand the scaling reasons behind this principle.

But for this application, one process (nodeJS/node-postgres) **subsumes** the other process (postgres). And the processes usually don't scale horizontally (due to the nature of relational databases like PostgreSQL). So, the correspondence between the two processes is 1:1, and typically, there is usually only one instance of the db.

This is why I'd like to dispense with the added complexity of involving docker-compose or k8s, and simply give others an image that can run the database with a different surface language. It is easier than having to tell others that they just have to set up a network between two containers using docker-compose or another technology.

Comment: I suggest to use two separate images anyways. Even if we deploy to, e.g., k8s, we have the pssibility to either deploy those two images as two deployments, or to deploy to containers within one pod.

Comment: Two separate containers is definitely the standard pattern here.  In Kubernetes, the database would have a StatefulSet, and the frontend a separate Deployment.  If you decided you didn't need the frontend, your other applications could still use the database.  If you needed to update the frontend in some way, you could do it without restarting the database.

Comment: I agree with the others, that best practice is to have things split. However, the dockerfile and whole project for the dockerhub image is here; https://bitbucket.org/spittet/node-postgresql/src/master/ and it's not impressive

Comment: If you really want to make one image only. You will have to make a ubuntu (or other os) image, install both inside and save that image.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is designed to run one process in a confined space (the container). Now if you want to run a database and nodejs inside one container, it means two processes and you have to tweak a lot which means overhead in the docker world.
Hence definitely go for two containers: one running the database, one running nodejs.

To ensure only one of them is reachable just put the two containers on a dedicated network and only tell docker to make the nodejs container reachable.

This can be done via docker-compose, but also k8s will support this model.
As a side effect, since this is the 'industry standard' for such cases, you can get a lot of support here.